# NullPointerException while calling Intent for Setting

Tags: android, android-intent

In my code, I displayed an alert dialog when the internet is not available. In that dialog I set a message "Internet Not Available." In that dialog I put two buttons 'Refresh' & 'Setting'. When the internet's gone & dialog comes, I clicked on Setting button it gives

This is the error (Logcat).

```
E: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: 
        com.appiphy.spacecomp.spinnerframework1, PID: 30424
           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread
    android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object
    reference

           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3823)
           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3784)
           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
           at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4094)
           at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4062)
           at com.appiphy.spacecomp.spinnerframework1.activity.MainActivity$10.onClick(MainActivity.java:967)
           at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

---

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
```

I used above line to open Settings on a device.

How to solve the above error?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: This code is perfect its working in my case.

Comment: Your dialog is outside of an activity. Try this `context.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog));
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("No internet connec" +
                            "" +
                            "tion on your device. Would you like to enable it?")
                    .setTitle("No Internet Connection")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(" Enable Internet ",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
                                    dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(dialogIntent);
                                }
                            });

            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(" Cancel ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alert.show();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether your dialog is inside your activity or in some other utility class. If its outside the activity, then you should use context to start the intent. You can pass the context of the activity, and call 
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
                mContext.startActivity(intent); mContext is the context which you will pass fro the activity.